# Html - space between logo and navbar

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out why this happens:

[image]

I can't find an error, i tried many solutions but they didn't solve the problem. Plz help

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.logo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
.active {
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html" class="logo">
  <img src="img/logo.png" width=400em height=150em></img>
</a>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you can try using a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).

Comment: Can you please upload [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) link with your working code? Are you sure there's no bottom margin in the logo (image), also make sure logo image's css has no margin in the bottom and navigational menu has no margin-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `display: block;` on the image ...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.logo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.logo img {
  display: block;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
.active {
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="index.html" class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png" width="400em" height="150em">
  </a>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css

```
img {  
 display: block;
}
```

Your `img` tag is also malformed - it should look like this:

```
<img src="img/logo.png" width="400em" height="150em" />
```